# list-packages says certificate has expired. What I need to do?

Tags: package, package-repositories

I have not used Emacs for about six months. Today I tried to use `M-x list-packages` and there is an error, although I remember that there was no such error before:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

I use Emacs 27.1 on 32-bit Windows 7, there is no antivirus software running. I also tried to reboot. And I also tried to install Emacs 28.1, but it seems it is 64-bit only.

How can I fix this, any ideas? Is it OK to simply ignore it?